# My Google Chrome profile can't open correctly

Tags: fedora, chrome

When I open Google Chrome (Stable version), I see the following dialog box:

> Your profile could not be opened correctly. Some features may be unavailable. Please check that the profile exists and you have permission to read and write its contents

I know for sure this problem happened only on Linux (Fedora 18) because when I use my Chrome profile in Windows, nothing goes wrong.

Also, I always get a bug report about `google-chrome-stable` version (I always update the system and Chrome too).

How do I resolve this problem without losing any data in my profile?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this error several times and here is the way how i fixed it:

1. Close Chrome.
2. Delete the file named *Web Data* in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default.
3. Start Chrome again and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just removed `rm -rf Web\ Data` from `~/.config/chromium/Default`.

- had to restart computer.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to look for chrome zombie processes. I've killed all of them and then chrome started to work ok again.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-owning your files.
`sudo chown -R username:username /home/username`

This should not mess up anything (as files in your home should be owned by your own user). By the way... Chrome gave me this error when I downgraded. (I had to delete my profile and use sync.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on my Fedora system, but the problem was not actually caused by incorrect permissions.

My `/tmp` drive was completely full (with Google Chrome tempfiles, no less!), so there was no room for Chrome to create a new temp directory to do whatever it needed to do to load my profile!

The following command fixed the problem (you shouldn't need to `sudo` this command unless multiple users on your system have launched the `google-chrome` app):

```
rm -rf /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has a discussion about this issue. And the reply from kyron works for me:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/IoQgoKuGh2E/2iJNqAnJ4bgJ

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but....

None of the solutions about deleting Web Data, create new profiles, etc worked for me on my CentOS 7 box.  Here's what did work:

```
sudo setsebool -P unconfined_chrome_sandbox_transition off
```

I've submitted a bug to Google because I shouldn't have to disable that boolean to get Chrome to work.

Answer (score 0):

That did it for me on Fedora 22:

- Shut down Chrome
- `mv ~/.config/google-chrome/Default /tmp`
- `mv /tmp/Default ~/.config/google-chrome`

Not data lost